# Mean value theorem and $(1-x^2)^n\ge 1-nx^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-explanation

**Theorem:**  $(1-x^2)^n\ge 1-nx^2$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

**Proof:** Let $f(x)=(1-x^2)^n-(1-nx^2)$. Then $f(0)=0$. Moreover, $f'(x)=2nx(1-(1-x^2)^{n-1})>0$ on $(0,1)$. The result now follows from the Mean Value Theorem.

I do not understand how the result follows from the Mean Value Theorem. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: What does the mean value theorem tell you?

Comment: For $x \in (0,1]$, apply the mean value theorem on the interval $[0,x]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean value theorem tells us that

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(\xi)$$

for some $\xi\in(0,x)$.

Given that $f'(\xi)\ge0$ and that

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}x\ge f(x),\quad x\in(0,1)$$

what does this tell you about $f(x)$? (Particularly, whether or not $f(x)$ is greater than, less than, or equal to $0$.)